# How to set the current date time to a Netsuite Date/time Field from SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite

I want to set the current date time to a custom Date/time entity field from suitescript.
I tried setting the Javascript date, it doesn't work.

I found a way to set the date but not the date time.

Answer (score 3):

Can you also try using nlapiDateToString(new Date(), 'datetime')?

Answer (score 2):

In the NetSuite Help, there is a page called 'DateTime Time Zone APIs' containing information about the `nlapiGetDateTimeValue` and `nlapiSetDateTimeValue`. These are probably the functions you are looking for.

Comment: Learning to navigate NetSuite's help documentation is so important.

Answer (score 1):

Before the record is submitted to the database it'll pick up the system date and time and commit the record.
Here's the code. Hope it helps.

```
function userEventBeforeSubmit(type) {
if (type == 'create' || type == 'edit') {
    var currentDate = sysDate(); // returns the date
    var currentTime = timestamp(); // returns the time stamp in HH:MM:SS
    var currentDateAndTime = currentDate + ' ' + currentTime;
    nlapiSetFieldValue('custentity_date_time', currentDateAndTime);
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'User Event Script', currentDateAndTime);
}
}

function sysDate() {
var date = new Date();
var tdate = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1; // jan = 0
var year = date.getFullYear();
return currentDate = month + '/' + tdate + '/' + year;
```

}

```
function timestamp() {
var str = "";

var currentTime = new Date();
var hours = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
var meridian = "";
if (hours > 12) {
    meridian += "pm";
} else {
    meridian += "am";
}
if (hours > 12) {

    hours = hours - 12;
}
if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
}
str += hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " ";

return str + meridian;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is answered here.  Must get object for record and do api call from object.
http://codeboxllc.com/ksc/author/mhson1978/page/3/